# Accessing RDS instance that is in a private VPC via terraform run in bitbucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

At my work we have a private VPC with RDS in it. In that VPC is also a bastion host that is only accessable via the aws cli command: (`aws ssm start-session -document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost`)

Via terraform I can manage the envoirement, create the VPC, RDS, Bastionhost and everthing else.

But I'm struggling a bit on how to actualy seed data (creating databases, schemas and roles) into the rds instance via terraform (using https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cyrilgdn/postgresql/latest/docs)

Is there somehow a way to let bitbucket pipelines connect to the RDS instance (maybe via ssm) and create the required resources in the RDS?

Answer (score 0):

Terraform is great for setting up your infrastructure, but it's a stretch to use it for managing data. Other tools can handle database seeding much better, like SQL scripts or Python scripts with SQLAlchemy, or even Ansible.

But if you're set on using Terraform, you can still try it. The tricky part is getting Bitbucket Pipelines to connect to your RDS instance via the Bastion host. You can use Bitbucket Pipelines SSH Pipe to make a tunnel to your Bastion host.

Here's a code that will do it:

```
script:
  - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.2.8
    variables:
      SSH_USER: 'ec2-user'
      SERVER: 'my.bastion.host'
      COMMAND: 'aws ssm start-session --target i-0123456789abcdef0'
```

Once you've set up that tunnel, connecting to your RDS instance is smooth sailing.

For the Terraform part, you'll want to use the PostgreSQL provider. You can create a new PostgreSQL database and a role and grant that role all privileges.

Don't forget to ensure your RDS security group lets connections through from the Bastion host.

Finally, if you're looking to insert data into your database, I recommend using a tool designed for that. Terraform is excellent, but it's not built for handling data, such as SQL scripts or Python scripts with SQLAlchemy.